# What is Python first argument? sys.argv[0] or sys.argv[1]

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments

According to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

`first argument is always script name and it is also being counted in number of arguments.`

which is `sys.argv[0]`

However, when I read other tutorial such as

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-command-line-arguments-argv-example/

it says that first argument is `sys.argv[1]`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
__author__ = 'nixCraft'
import sys total = len(sys.argv)
cmdargs = str(sys.argv)
print ("The total numbers of args passed to the script: %d " % total)
print ("Args list: %s " % cmdargs)
# Pharsing args one by one
print ("Script name: %s" % str(sys.argv[0]))
print ("First argument: %s" % str(sys.argv[1]))
print ("Second argument: %s" % str(sys.argv[2]))
```

Which one is correct and should be followed?

This is confusing especially to those who just started learning programming and Python.

Comment: could just run your code and find out..

Comment: I did, that why I put the sample code above.

Comment: The best way to think of it is that `sys.argv` is going to be a list of the things *after* the call to `python` in your shell, so, for example, `python myscript.py foo bar baz`, everything after python is `myscript.py foo bar baz` so `sys.argv == ['myscript.py', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']` So, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) are the docs which go into more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script.  Technically it is the "first" argument, but is typically of no use to you, unless you don't know the name of the file you're executing.  `sys.argv[1]`, is the name of the first argument after the name of the script, so the first useful argument.

Comment: Thanks @Gabe for helping me. It seems like Stack Overflow is getting unfriendly from day to day.

Not everyone knows everything .. some people just started and simply just want the answer.